# Empty JSON Array when using @Groups annotation with JMS Serializer and FOSRestBundle v2.1

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to use the `@Groups` annotation to serialize my data but I'm just receiving an empty array.

I've tried using `@Serializer\Expose` on the fields I want to show up, but then they show up everywhere and ignore the groups.

From what I've read I'm pretty sure that I should only need to use the `@Groups` annotation but I just end up with this (there are two schedule entities):

```
{
  "schedules": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

There seems to have been a change to how this is supposed to work, I've found examples for previous versions FOSRestBundle, I just have not been able to port them over to the new version.

From what I understand you can set groups in the serializer context and use that to set the views context, but I've had no luck with that.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/UPGRADING-2.0.md

> View::setSerializationContext and View::getSerializationContext have been removed. Use View::setContext and View::getContext together with the new Context class instead.
>
> Before:
>
> ```
> use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;
>
> $view = new View();
> $context = new SerializationContext();
> $view->setSerializationContext($context);
> $context = $view->getSerializationContext();
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;
>
> $view = new View();
> $context = new Context();
> $view->setContext($context);
> $context = $view->getContext();
> ```

I'm having a hell of a time getting my head around all this, and would ever so grateful for any assistance to point me in the right direction.

As well as the following I attempted to `use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;`  and
`@Rest\View(serializerGroups({"schedule"})` annotation with the  on the controller, it had the same effect as I'm seeing now (*ie* none).

Schedule Controller

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;

class ScheduleController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @param $date
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function getSchedulesScheduleAction($date)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        list($startDate, $endDate) = $this->get('radio.utils.date_and_time')->findWeekRange($date);
        $schedules = $em->getRepository('RadioBundle:Schedule')->findByRange($startDate, $endDate);

        $view = $this->view(
            [
                'schedules' => $schedules,
            ],
            200
        );

        $context = new Context();
        $context->setGroups(["schedule"]);
        $view->setContext($context);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

Schedule Entity

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * Schedule
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="schedule")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RadioBundle\Repository\ScheduleRepository")
 * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Schedule
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Serializer\Groups({"schedule"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="datetime")
\     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Serializer\Groups({"schedule"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $endTime;



    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Serializer\Groups({"schedule"})
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RadioBundle\Entity\RadioShow", inversedBy="schedule")
     */
    private $radioShow;

    ...
```

app/config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json

jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
```

Comment: What you've done looks identical to how I use contexts, with the exception of I use $context->addGroup('group'); instead of setGroups. I also do use expose combined with groups and it works as advertised.

Comment: I spotted that, since I posted it, I tried `$context->addGroup('schedule')`, `$context->addGroups(['schedule'])` and the `$context->setGroups(['schedule'])` still nothing. I'll try again though, I've run through a few things since.

Comment: Thank you so much. That did the trick, using `$context->setGroups(['schedule'])`, I also needed to use `@Serializer\Expose` on the `@Group` fields.

Comment: I can accept that as an answer if you want to post it.

Comment: No problem, glad to help, done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ExclusionPolicy("all") on the entity you will need to expose the property with the groups.

E.g.

```
   /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Serializer\Groups({"schedule"})
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $startTime;
```